# How to stop the model from deforming while it rotates?

Tags: modeling, keyframes

I am creating a rotating gif of one of my characters (following the video tutorial by Cherylynn Lima on YouTube). I have made one of these before but have not come across this particular problem:

[image]

(sorry for the low quality gif!! I'm sure can provide a higher resolution to you directly if you need it)

As you can see, the arms (and I think the tail as well) rotate strangely. My fox friend is meant to maintain this pose while rotating:

[image]

I'm not sure what I did wrong. I have an armature set up, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the problem.

I'm also still fairly new to Blender, so any help at all is welcome!

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Added the file (See comments)

Comment: Are you animating the rotation of the Fox mesh object or the armature that controls it?

Comment: I am rotating the mesh in that gif. When I try to rotate the Armature instead, nothing rotates.

Comment: I asked because it looks like there is something that is stuck in position and the mesh deforms when rotating around it.

Comment: That gif is awesome. If you want solution exactly for your case you can [upload the blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and include link here in comments so someone looks at it

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your armature. As you said, you are rotating the mesh, and if you rotate the armature, nothing happens. Delete any parenting and armature modifier, I guess this should do the trick. If not, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: I deleted the parenting and armature modifier, however my model reverted back to T-pose. I'll be uploading the file as you suggested. I'm sure someone will see something that I'm missing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here's the file! https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3929/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems to work as it should. Don't rotate your mesh directly after applying an armature - after this point, only the armature is responsible for the moving.

In *pose mode*, you can move and rotate all bones to modify your mesh. If you want to rotate the entire armature (and your mesh with it), leave the *pose mode* and rotate the armature in *object mode*.